# Magento Image upload missing?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm having some issues with a Magento install 1.7.0.2. We recently moved servers and now the image upload option on newsletters and CMS pages are not working. (Product images are working fine).

Media folder is set for 777 permissions as well as subfolders.

I am getting this when trying to add an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyl31.png

The create folder button also does nothing, has anyone come across this before or know a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Javascript compression in Magento was the issue. Disabling compression made this work! Don't know why.

Comment: i have check in my case merge js and css option is no but same issue. please suggest your idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure it is able to read the /media/wysiwyg directory?
2. Have you set the base URLs correctly under System / Web?
3. Have you copied over the js-directory?

Comment: Hi Sander, sorry for the delayed reply.  /media/wysiwyg is set to 0777.

Base URL is fine everything else works apart from this image upload.

All JS files are there.

This is really confusing me.